Dispatch Auto-Start Service on Android TV problems with Accessibility
I am trying to enable auto-srtart on my android tv with dispatch, but the problem is that my android TV, for some reason, does not have an accessibility setting. What should I do?
I tried ADB from my Mac and it does not seem to find it.
Here's what I do
(base) xxxxxxxxxx@MacBook-Pro ~ % adb shell am start -a android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS
Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS flg=0x10000000 }
(base) xxxxxxxxxx@MacBook-Pro ~ % adb shell am start -a android.settings.SETTINGS

it means your android tv does not support opening an activity for the Accessibility intent. I have the same with my Nvidia Shield tv. You can still open the accessibility settings manually through the settings menu.

When you start the Activity from the menu check the logcat to see what's the Intent
